# How to change Target link of menu in OpenCart

Tags: menu, opencart

I am beginner in OpenCart and customizing a theme, I want to change the target link of site Menu, for example If a blow Image is my menu:

[image: Site Menu]

I want to change target link of *Bedroom menu* to *#cmsblock-22*, I search in CMS panel of OpenCart but nothing found, could any one help me to change this link, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "Living Room", "Dinning Room" & "Bedroom" all are categories which listed on menu as shown in image.

You can change link of this by simply going to admin > catalog > category > edit category (which link you want to change) > click on data tab > scroll down to SEO URL input field and fill the input with "**#cmsblock-22**".

Above will work only if you have seo url enabled in admin settings. So, please make sure that you have enabled this setting.

If not,
Go to admin > system > setting > click edit > click server tab > check yes in front of **Use SEO URLs**.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change it from admin panel

In admin panel, go to Catalog->Category 
Find for **Bedroom** and edit it.

Hopes this might help you